# Как упростить присваивание полей объектов?

Tags: php

Вот код:

```
$user = VK::getUser($userID);
$this->id = $user->id; // $this - объект того же класса, что и $user
$this->name = $user->name;
// и так далее...
```

Comment: А чем вам конструкция [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php) не угодила?

Comment: Не понял, как ей пользоваться в данной ситуации

Comment: Раз `$this` объект того же класса, что и `$user`, то вам достаточно _на более высоком уровне_ склонировать `$user` и уже потом с ним работать. Хотя для этого нужно быть уверенным, что клонирование корректно работает на объектах типа `$user`.

Comment: $this = clone($user); ???

Comment: Во-первых `clone` - не функция, а во-вторых, это действие нужно проводить _на более высоком уровне_ (а не в области видимости методов класса).